# How to get the value of a DateTimeField in peewee

Tags: python, sql, peewee

```
class Test(Model):
    time = DateTimeField()

# ...
row = Test.select()[0]
test.time
```

This returns a string that looks like this: `2017-01-23 01:01:39+01:00`. How can I get it as a datetime object instead? Do I have to parse it manually?

Also I would be interested if there is any documentation on how to use the `DateTimeField`. The official documentation doesn't have anything on it.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using SQLite? If so, SQLite doesn't have a dedicated datetime type, so datetimes are stored as strings in the DB. What peewee will do is recognize certain datetime formats coming out of the DB and convert them to datetime objects. What you need to do is ensure that either:

1. When you create/save your object, that you assign a `datetime` object to the field.
2. When reading back pre-existing data, that the data is in a recognized format.

The formats peewee supports out-of-the-box for datetime field are:

- YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS.ffffff
- YYYY-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
- YYYY-mm-dd

It looks like your has zone info. I'd suggest converting to UTC and dropping the zone info. That should fix it.

Comment: That was it. But how to keep tzinfo? It's better to store tzinfo…

Comment: You'll have to implement a custom type to store those in Sqlite, since it doesn't have a dedicated datetime type. As I wrote in my comment, it *only* makes sense to store UTC in sqlite, due to the fact that it's represented as a string. Or conversely use TimestampField, which is stored as an integer UTC timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding a default like this?

`time = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())`

Or when adding an entry add it as a datetime.datetime object directly:

`test = Test(....., time=datetime.datetime.strptime("2018-3-15", '%Y-%m-%d'))`

In the second case you don't need to specify anything in the class definition...

Comment: My question is not about writing data to the database, it's about reading data back into a python object.

Comment: Alrighty, if I try it locally with my suggestions I get datetime.datetime objects as return values.

If you have no access to how the data gets written into the database I suppose you need to parse it. 
You could then use:

`datetime.datetime.strptime("2017-01-23 01:01:39+0100", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S%z")`

The only problem is, that you need to change the format of the timezone so that datetime can read it. You need to remove the colon in the timezone part