# Peewee select query on a datetime field does not return a datetime object

Tags: python, peewee

Hi I have a datetime field in my model, while executing select query on the model peewee returns a string representation of the datetime field instead of an actual datetime object.

```
past_day = Model.select(Model, fn.MAX(Model.timestamp))[0].timestamp 
# timestamp is a field of type DateTimeField() ; above query returns a str object

type(past_day) # prints str.
```

I want to get the pure python datetime object from this query, i looked everywhere but not getting a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50428947/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-datetimefield-in-peewee this is what i was looking for. closing the question

Comment: what version of Peewee do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Works fine as far as I can tell:

```
db = SqliteDatabase(':memory:')

class R(Model):
    key = TextField()
    ts = DateTimeField()
    class Meta:
        database = db

db.create_tables([R])

for i in range(1, 10):
    R.create(key=str(i), ts=datetime.datetime(2020, 1, i))
r = R.select(R, fn.MAX(R.ts).alias('max_ts')).get()
print(r.key, type(r.max_ts), r.max_ts)
```

Prints:

```
9 <class 'datetime.datetime'> 2020-01-09 00:00:00
```

Try upgrading if you are using an outdated version of Peewee.